# Is Redbull haram to consume

Tags: halal-haram

I was on the internet and I saw a article and a video that it's made of bull semen and I know that semen is haram to consume please answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may as well be a very obvious rumor , by doing a quick search , [here](https://energydrink-us.redbull.com/en/red-bull-does-not-contain-bull-sperm) is redbull's reply to that claim .

- PS : You really shouldn't believe any unsupported claim on the internet.